# How to do the relationship 0..1 from uml

Tags: java, uml, relationship

[image: UML diagram]

I need to know how to do the relationship between DibujoSVG and Lienzo.
I have done all other relationships but I don't know how to do this one.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference with the others relationships ? Between `Coordonada` and the top which we don't see for example. What's bothering you ?

Comment: I only need the relation between DibujoSVG and Lienzo. Could be only to create a Lienzo in DibujoSVG? The difference is that this one only has got 0..1 on its arrow no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0..1 relationship means "optional" - ClassA has a reference to ClassB, but this reference may be empty.

An extra complication is which side owns the relationship, so you could have this:

```
class Lienzo {

}

class DibujoSVG {
    private Lienzo lienzo;
}
```

But you could also have `Lienzo` owning the relationship, and the business rule that `DibujoSVG` instances are never shared (but not strictly enforced by the language):

```
class Lienzo {
    // Never shared.
    private DibujoSVG dibujoSvg;
}

class DibujoSVG {
}
```

Since this still leaves the possibility that a given `DibujoSVG` instance has not been linked to a `Lienzo` instance, it's still implementing the 0..1 multiplicity.

The second is, in my experience, the more usual way to do this, since you usually need to navigate outwards in the object graph rather than inwards.

Comment: Thank you - if you find this has answered your question, could you please mark it accepted to close the question?